# jdbc issue on tomcat6 with birt

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, jdbc, driver

first and foremost, i know very little about tomcat6, and it's been a long time since i've done complex java work.

so my friends server went down, and i'm trying to get things working on a new system (Ubuntu 12.04, with Tomcat6).

his site had a link to some birt reports, but they aren't working.  it looks like there is a problem with the jdbc mysql driver.

here is what i've got:
in catalina.sh, i've got

```
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java
```

in that directory, i've got (obviously, more in here than just these things):

```
mysql-connector-java-5.1.16.jar
mysql-connector-java.jar
mysql.jar
```

the birt stuff is deployed in /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/WebViewerExample , and in there i see the WEB-INF/lib directory, to which i've also copied the mysql-connector jar files.

i set birt up so that it will log stuff, and this is the error it's giving me:

```
Sep 1, 2012 3:49:51 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager loadExtraDriver
SEVERE: refreshUrlsWhenFail: true
Sep 1, 2012 3:49:51 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager loadExtraDriver
SEVERE: driverClassPath: null
Sep 1, 2012 3:49:51 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager loadExtraDriver
SEVERE: Registered URLs:
Sep 1, 2012 3:49:51 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager findDriver
WARNING: Failed to load JDBC driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Sep 1, 2012 3:49:51 PM org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ConnectionManager openConnection
SEVERE: Unable to open connection.
org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: Cannot load JDBC Driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.findDriver(JDBCDriverManager.java:782)
.... Huge stack trace...
```

so i don't know a lot about java and tomcat.  any clue on what i can do to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jars like `JDBC` drivers should be added into global classpath. You need to put the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.16.jar` to tomcat's lib directory. Put it into `${tomcat.dir}/lib` folder and remove `mysql` jar from `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: when i look in /var/lib/tomcat6, there is no lib directory.  should i make one?  i'm assuming that is the location of ${tomcat.dir}.

Comment: ok, so in ubuntu, `${tomcat.dir}` is `/usr/share/tomcat6`.  within there is the lib folder.  i created a symlink in `lib` with the name `mysql-connector-java.jar`, pointing to `/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar`.  restarted tomcat.  getting the same result (same error message).  any other suggestions?

Comment: so i've gotten far enough that i now have a different error: `SEVERE: Unable to open connection.
org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: There is an error in get connection, Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server..
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.doConnect(JDBCDriverManager.java:264)`.  so it looks like it's finding the driver now, just not connecting.  no errors in the mysql logs.  any suggestions?

Comment: so what you had worked.  my problem later was that the IP address was hardcoded into the Birt files (not localhost), and mysql wasn't binding on that address.  changed the my.cnf so mysql would bind on all addresses, gave the user access within mysql, and voila, it works.